# Selenium Webdriver uses external URL Stream Handler?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Dear Webdriver Experts,

I am wondering whether it is possible for Selenium Webdriver such as Firefox, to use a different URL stream handler to use, as opposed to using its own natively generated handler?

I am in the position to generate a lower level HTTP tunneling program written in Java, which allows subsequent URL connections to tunnel through and access resouces in private LANs.

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Browsermob-proxy](http://bmp.lightbody.net/) which enables you to do all sort of things with URL (and other stuff).